# Write firebase function and schedule time to send notification android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that triggers the date to the firebase database node and sending notification when user inputs data to the android device. I want to to schedule timer to send this notification using an external cron job.I have the code below that successfully sends notification as soon as the user enters the date. Can any one help me please as I'm finding really hard to understand it.What do I have to modify to make it work?

This is the index.js

```
    var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/description/{descId}')
        .onWrite(event => {

        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;
        var str1 = "Your profile title is ";
        var str2 = "Date is ";
        var strProfile = str1.concat(eventSnapshot.child("title").val());
        var strStatus = str2.concat(eventSnapshot.child("date").val());
        console.log(strProfile);
        console.log(strStatus)

        var topic = "android";
        var payload = {
            data: {
                title: eventSnapshot.child("title").val(),
                date: eventSnapshot.child("date").val()
            }
        };

        // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
                // contents of response.
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
        });
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService Activity

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), remoteMessage.getData().get("date"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String date) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("title  is " + title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alex)
                .setContentText("your deadline date is " + date)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with the help of `AlarmManager`. When user inputs a date, get that date and set an Alarm for that specific date and time like this:

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileList.this, 
IntentBroadcastedReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(ProfileList.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

Then you have to set up a Broadcast Receiver to handle the event. In onReceive() method of your Broadcast Receiver, you will call your web-service to send the request to your server.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Call your web-service here.

}
}
```

Don't forget to define receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do I make that work with the code that I have already written? I'm still confused as I'm a android beguinner